# Downloaded Link invalid

Tags: windows, azure-devops

i have this follow issue.

I Created with my pipeline a "setup folder" with "Test" in this folder is a relase folder with source code.
on the same stage there is a link with a default path to the exe file.

My Tests maschine has both win10.
With Maschine 1 i downloaded the folder, decomprise it and the link is valid.
On my Second maschine is the link not valid, cause the system dont updated it and it has the "default" path in it.

Has some one a idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maschine 2 and the default path has the same Volumne Char....
So when you are use another Volumne char than is all OK

Comment: Glad that the issue can be resolved, and thanks for sharing the answer. Maybe, you can accept yourself answer as the solution of this case. This could be also helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.